# can i use prometheus without docker and kuber?

Tags: python, docker, prometheus, monitoring

I was wondering if there is any way to use Prometheus (as a playground, to see how it works) without needing to dockerize the app and deploy it on kuber (kind or minikube)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to dockerize the Prometheus just to try it out.

Regarding trying it on non containerized environment, there are multiple options.

1. Use the demo(hosted) Prometheus to check its features, query the data etc :
   https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph
2. You can simple download the binary and run it on your Windows / Linux based systems :
   https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/releases/latest